# I would like to block the login for the Management Console (AKA Carbon) from the API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I read on the documentation that you could block the Management console with the following command
wso2server.bat --run -DworkerNode
However, when I type such command, the api manager doesn't run at all.
When I run profiles such as
-Dprofile=api-store -Dprofile=api-publisher together (to avoid the management console), it doesn't allow me to enter to neither. 
And when I run the -Dprofile=api-store, it still allows me to login into the management console.

Can I use the -DworkerNode? I don't want to be able to login into the management console.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict access to `/carbon` by putting this to `repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to certain folders</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted folders</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/carbon/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```